# How to get system time zone configuration

Tags: java

Is there a way to get the System timezone configuration on which the JVM is running? I would like to get the format in a human readable format like `Europe/London` and `09:50:07`.

Answer (score 3):

`TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName();` //will display time zone name e.g. India Standard Time

and

`TimeZone.getDefault().getID();` //will display id e.g. Asia/Calcutta

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of how you can get the TimeZone from a Calendar

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
TimeZone timeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
```

Comment: What will be the output?

Comment: For example timeZone.getDisplayName() returns "India Standard Time" and timeZone.getID() return "Asia/Calcutta"

Comment: Cab I also display additionally something like this `+5` (time zone difference)